# Showing range of dates on calendar

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to select a date that is within a 15 day period from today from a calendar and saving that on my database.

I have tried setting max and min values but its not working. Do you know what is the error or if there is another way to do this.
thank you!

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFecha" type="date" runat="server" min="01/09/2019" max="19/09/2019" style="width:230px"OnTextChanged="txtFecha_TextChanged">Seleccione fecha</asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: you could use a dropdown list and populate the allowed dates. Or you could use checkboxes.If you post your code not just the textbox and let us know what actually the problem is somebody might be able to help better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using jquery ui datepicker.

> Restrict the range of selectable dates with the minDate and maxDate options. Set the beginning and end dates as actual dates (new Date(2009, 1 - 1, 26)), as a numeric offset from today (-20), or as a string of periods and units ('+1M +10D'). For the last, use 'D' for days, 'W' for weeks, 'M' for months, or 'Y' for years.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Restrict date range</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: new Date(2019, 08, 01), maxDate: new Date(2019, 08, 19)});
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```